# Con Javascript, me aparece este error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle = "#000000";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
    <canvas id="game" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <title>Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Estoy intentando dibujar un cuadrado negro pero al ejecutar me aparece este error: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')".

Answer (score 0):

> La función se ejecutara una vez finalizada la carga de la pagina
> también podría usarse

......windows.setTimeout().....windows.setInterval()

[explicación en developer mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage)

```js
const ancho=400;
const alto=600;
// funcion para obtener el objeto del contexto de canvas
function Contexto(canvas){
   var elemento = document.getElementById(canvas);
   // verfificamos al contexto
   if(elemento && elemento.getContext){
   // load canvas
      var contexto = elemento.getContext('2d');
      if(contexto){
         return contexto;
      }
   }
   return FALSE;
}
window.onload=function(){
// verificamos canvas
 var contexto = Contexto('canvas');

  if(contexto){
  contexto.fillStyle = "black";
  contexto.fillRect(0, 0,ancho,alto);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"  ></canvas>
    <title>Game</title>
```